# Output de loop dentro de outro loop com SQL e PHP

Tags: php, sql, xml

Eu tenho esses valores no meu banco de dados SQL, quero uma saída dessa maneira e esse arquivo no navegador usando PHP

Estrutura de banco de dados com os valores que eu quero na saída
**Minhas tentativas, embora não ajude vocês em nada: [pastebin.com/6tCNbpY4](http://pastebin.com/6tCNbpY4)**

```
DATABASE schedule

TABLE stream_playlist
id  streamname      |   playlistname |  repeat |  scheduled
=====================================================================
1   stackoverflow   |   plname1      |  true   |  2009-12-11 16:25:05
2   other_stream    |   plother2     |  false  |  2011-11-11 17:01:11



TABLE videos_for_stream_playlist
id |  streamname     | src                    |  start |  length
================================================================
1  |  other_stream   | http:/ local/demo.mp4  |  60    |  -1
2  |  stackoverflow  | C:\sample.mp4          |  0     |  20
3  |  other_stream   | otherlocation/mystream |  0     |  -1
```

O output deve ser escrito em um arquivo.txt e exibido no navegador ao executar o script PHP.
Os videos podem ser ordenados por `id`.

```
<smil>
  <body>

    <stream name="stackoverflow"></stream>

    <playlist name="plname1" playOnStream="stackoverflow" repeat="true" scheduled="2009-12-11 16:25:05">
        <video src="C:\sample.mp4" start="0" length="20"/>
    </playlist>


    <stream name="other_stream"></stream>

    <playlist name="plother2" playOnStream="other_stream" repeat="false" scheduled="2011-11-11 17:01:11">
        <video src="http:/ local/demo.mp4" start="60" length="-1"/>
        <video src="otherlocation/mystream" start="0" length="-1"/>
    </playlist>

  </body>
</smil>
```

Como posso fazer isso? Não consigo dar um *loop* funcional dentro de outro *loop*, sai tudo duplicado.

Comment: Pelo que parece, você precisa de 2 loops separados, e nao um dentro do outro. E se realmente precisa do txt intermediário, aí são 2 questões bem diferentes. Uma é como gerar o txt a partir do SQL, outra é mostrar o txt no browser. Pelo que eu vi do seu código, melhor você resolver a primeira tabela, e depois de resolvida, fazer o código para resolver a segunda, aproveitando a conexão. No mesmo PHP, mas uma parte depois da outra, e não misturando.

Comment: Você precisa principalmente explicar melhor o que quer e o que está funcionando ou não. Quebre o problema em etapas e pergunte uma de cada vez. Por exemplo, vc consegue conectar no DB e ler os dados? Se não pergunte só sobre essa parte. Se sim, passe para a etapa seguinte. Do jeito que está perguntando, alguém vai ter que escrever o programa inteiro para vc para resolver.

Comment: Desculpe a minha arrogância. Obrigado @Bacco vou seguir esse seu exemplo, mentalizei o código e acho que já tenho uma ideia de como começar a fazer. Obrigado.

Comment: nao seria mais pratico fazer uma query somente e ter um unico loop ?

Comment: Não acho @Otto, pois como o amigo Harry Potter respondeu, exite um loop para os _vídeos_ também, o que eu já sábia que teria que ter, porem não imaginava como poderia ser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Exemplo:*

Funciona assim, pego todos os itens da tabela `stream_playlist`, faça um foreach no mesmo, 
e em cada item chama um outra `SQL` da tabela de relação `videos_for_stream_playlist` pelo campo streamname.

```
<smil>
  <body>
<?php
    $pdo   = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', 'senha');
    $query = $pdo->query('SELECT * FROM stream_playlist');
    foreach($query as $row) {
?>
    <stream name="<?php echo $row['streamname'];?>"></stream>
    <playlist name="<?php echo $row['playlistname'];?>" 
              playOnStream="<?php echo $row['streamname'];?>" 
              repeat="<?php echo $row['repeat'];?>" 
              scheduled="<?php echo $row['scheduled'];?>">
<?php
    $sts = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM videos_for_stream_playlist WHERE streamname=?");
    $sts->bindValue(1,$row['streamname'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sts->execute();
    $result = $sts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $str){
?>    
        <video src="<?php echo $str['src'];?>" start="<?php echo $str['start'];?>" length="<?php echo $str['length'];?>"/>
<?php
    }
?>
    </playlist>    

<?php
    }
?>
  </body>
</smil>
```

*Obs: Esse modelo de tabela poderia ter relação com o `PrimaryKey` da tabela mãe porque a pesquisa seria mais rápida, performática não trazendo problemas futuros, ou seja, está sem  normalização*

---

Outra maneira seria com apenas uma `SQL` fazendo um Join e retornando dados associados por chave especifica (no `fetchAll` do `PDO`, essa junção `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC | PDO::FETCH_GROUP`).

```
<smil>
  <body>
<?php
    function Head($name,$playlistname,$repeat,$scheduled){
        return PHP_EOL.'<stream name="'.$playlistname.'"></stream>'.PHP_EOL.
              '<playlist name="'.$name.'" playOnStream="'.$playlistname.'" repeat="'.$repeat.'" scheduled="'.$scheduled.'">';
    }
    function Center($str){
        return PHP_EOL.'<video src="'.$str['src'].'" start="'.$str['start'].'" length="'.$str['length'].'"/>';
    }

    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1', 'root', 'senha');
    $sts = $pdo->prepare('SELECT a.streamname, b.streamname, a.playlistname, 
    a.repeat, a.scheduled, b.src, b.start, b.length
    FROM testdb.stream_playlist a inner join 
    videos_for_stream_playlist b on b.streamname=a.streamname 
    ORDER BY a.streamname asc');
    $sts->execute();
    $res = $sts->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC | PDO::FETCH_GROUP);     
    //var_dump($res);die();                
    foreach($res as $idx=>$value){          
        $repeat       = '';
        $scheduled    = '';
        $center       = '';
        $streamname   = '';
        $playlistname = '';
        foreach($value as $str){
            $center .= Center($str);            
            $repeat       = $str['repeat'];
            $scheduled    = $str['scheduled'];
            $streamname   = $str['streamname'];
            $playlistname = $str['playlistname'];           
        }
        echo Head($playlistname,$idx,$repeat,$scheduled); 
        echo $center;
        echo PHP_EOL.'</playlist>'.PHP_EOL;
    }    
?>
  </body>
</smil>
```

Answer (score 5):

Bom, da forma que foi marcada como solução eu vejo um problema, você vai chamar diversas vezes seu Banco de Dados para receber cada linha da primeira tabela o seu correspondente na segunda tabela, ou seja consumo.

Seu Select poderia ser feito de outra forma.

```
SELECT sp.*, vsp.* FROM stream_playlist sp INNER JOIN videos_for_stream_playlist vsp ON sp.streamname = vsp.streamname
```

Dessa forma seu select retornará exatamente o que você quer e com as duas tabelas em linha.

Ficaria algo do tipo.

```
TABELA DE RETORNO.
id  streamname      |   playlistname |  repeat |  scheduled             | id |  streamname     | src                    |  start |  length
=====================================================================================================================================
2   other_stream    |   plother2     |  false  |  2011-11-11 17:01:11   | 1  |  other_stream   | http:/ local/demo.mp4  |  60    |  -1
1   stackoverflow   |   plname1      |  true   |  2009-12-11 16:25:05   | 2  |  stackoverflow  | C:\sample.mp4          |  0     |  20
2   other_stream    |   plother2     |  false  |  2011-11-11 17:01:11   | 3  |  other_stream   | otherlocation/mystream |  0     |  -1
```

Só haverá um probleminha nesse comando que eu fiz, os nomes de alguns campos vão se repetir, então o ideal é fazer nomeando os campos diretamente.

```
SELECT sp.ID as spID, sp.streamname as spStreamName, sp.playlistname as spPlayListName ... FROM stream_playlist sp INNER JOIN videos_for_stream_playlist vsp ON sp.streamname = vsp.streamname
```

De preferencia omita um dos campos streamname já que ele com certeza serão exatamente iguais.

Comment: Só queria lembrar que se você tiver um resposta melhor em relação a pergunta, poste, e seja agraciado com votos ou até mudança da resposta da pergunta para você, o que importa aqui é criar um repositório de perguntas e resposta que possam ser usados por várias pessoas. Não adianta colocar meia resposta, porque o usuário queria também o output de saida do `PHP` com a junção das tabelas. Eu entendo o que você disse, posso concordo mediante fatores, mas, a sua resposta ainda continua incompleta. Não me leva a mau, só foi uma forma de dizer o que o SOPt espera da gente, Obrigado.

Comment: Não se trata de uma meia resposta, apenas uma demonstração de uma abordagem que não gere tantos acessos ao BD e que tenha a mesma saida, quanto as respostas que estão corretas ou erradas a sua está ai, correta e marcada como a tal.

Answer (score 4):

Verifique o codigo fonte do arquivo.
Se voce quiser armazenar em um arquivo texto, é só armazenar todos os `echo` em uma variável e escrever no arquivo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body id="page">
    <?php
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=config_server_schedule",     "root", "suporte");

    $rs = $con->query("SELECT * from stream_playlist");
    echo "<pre>" . "\n";
    echo '  <smil>' . "\n";
    echo '  <body>' . "\n";

    $streamname = array();

    while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
        $streamname[] = $row;
    }
    foreach ($streamname as $name) {
        //print_r($name);
        echo "\n" . '</playlist>' . "\n";
        echo "<stream name=\"{$name->streamname}\"></stream>" . "\n";

        $rs = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM videos_for_stream_playlist WHERE streamname=?");
        $rs->bindParam(1, $name->streamname);
        $rs->execute();
        ?>
    <playlist name="<?php echo $name->playlistname; ?>" playOnStream="<?php echo $name->streamname; ?>" repeat="<?php echo $name->repet; ?>" scheduled="<?php echo $name->scheduled; ?>">
        <?php
        while ($result = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) {
            //print_r($result);
            ?>
            <video src="<?php echo $result->src; ?>" start="<?php echo $result->starte; ?>" length="<?php echo $result->length; ?>"/>
            <?php
        }
        echo "\n" . '</playlist>' . "\n";
    }
    echo '  </smil>' . "\n";
    echo '  </body>' . "\n";
    ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sim, estou usando algo assim.
`$output .= "";
$output = "Meu códido";
echo $output;`
Logo, pego o resultado e posso gerencia-lo de acordo com o que eu precisar.