# Como guardar vários usuários para uma conta como o Netflix por exemplo

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, pdo

Seguinte, tenho uma aplicação que suporta apenas **1** conta por usuário, quero atualizar o banco de dados em `MySQL` para que ele suporte um sistema que seja possível guardar por exemplo, *contas filhos*, derivadas dessa *conta pai*, que é a principal.

Minha aplicação suporta apenas **1** conta por usuário como já foi dito, todas as informações da conta do usuário estão guardadas em apenas uma `row`.

**MySQL**

```
SQL |
    \-[Table] Users |
                    \-[rows] id  | UserID | Username | Resto...
                              1  |   845  |  João    |   ...
                              2  |   846  |  Mãria   |   ...
                             ... |   ...  |    ...   |   ...
```

Neste exemplo, temos João, ele tem 3 *filhos*, eu deveria dar suporte as sub-contas, mas não sei como fazer isso. As contas *filhos* precisam ter um `UserID` único **diferente das contas pais** para que o sistema possa processa-la baseado no `UserID` e assim fazer o processamento das outras informações, assim como excluir um *filho* quando for necessário.

**Filhos**

```
... | UserID | Username | Resto das configurações pessoas de cada filho...
... |  888   | F.João 1 | ...
... |  777   | F.João 2 | ...
... |  222   | F.João 3 | ...
... | outros |  filhos  | de outros usuários ...
```

***Existe alguma forma de fazer isso?***

> Se possível, mas não mais importante do que o `SQL`, gostaria de um
>   exemplo em `php` de como pegar esse *filho* e exclui-lo, baseado na conta *pai*,  que é a principal.

*Isso foi preciso pois os usuários não poderiam acessar em 2 plataformas diferentes com a mesma conta. Por isso preciso de um sistema baseado no netflix.*

Comment: O que você está precisando é um relacionamento "um para muitos". Crie uma nova tabela "profiles" e a relacione com sua tabela de "users".

Comment: Acho que entendi(na teoria, a pratica é sempre diferente), mas como a pergunta está aberta, é melhor esperar alguém responder. Obrigado pela dica.

Comment: Formularei uma resposta quando estiver folgado. Por enquanto, tente pesquisar sobre o relacionamento, creio que te ajudará a dar mais alguns passos.

Comment: Também pode fazer criando uma coluna `userParent` e quando um usuário for criado como *dependente*, basta relacionar o *userParent* com o *userID*. Posteriormente quando determinado *vinculo* deixar de existir entre os usuários, basta apagar o valor de *userParent*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Se as contas filhas fazem logon

Você pode utilizar `n:m` para uma tabela se relacionar com ela mesma, eu não posso afirmar que este é o melhor caminho, no entanto desta maneira você poderá ter níveis "infinitos" (filhos, netos, dependentes, sócio, esposa, etc), um exemplo com Mysql e innoDB:

[image: n:m na mesma tabela]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`usuarios` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`usuarios_has_usuarios` (
  `usuarios_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `usuarios_id1` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`usuarios_id`, `usuarios_id1`),
  INDEX `fk_usuarios_has_usuarios_usuarios1_idx` (`usuarios_id1` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_usuarios_has_usuarios_usuarios_idx` (`usuarios_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usuarios_has_usuarios_usuarios`
    FOREIGN KEY (`usuarios_id`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`usuarios` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_usuarios_has_usuarios_usuarios1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`usuarios_id1`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`usuarios` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

A vantagem de usar chave estrangeira, é que se houver usuários dependentes eles ficarão "amarrados" a outros usuários. Mesmo que você tente remover o usuário PAI (supondo que seja um acidente) a tabela não vai permitir isto. No entanto você pode sim usar o sem chave estrangeira, mas se você deletar ou atualizar algo errado, isto irá começar a exibir dados incoerentes.

Um exemplo sem chave estrangeira seria criar uma coluna a mais na tabela usuários:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`usuarios` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parentId` INT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = myIsam;
```

Permiti `NULL` na `parentId`, mas você também pode usar `NOT NULL` (que provavelmente ficará 0), não muda muita coisa.

### Se as contas filhas não fazem logon (serve apenas para salvar dados)

Conforme conversei com o autor, o objetivo não é ter logins para os filhos, apenas dados de preferencias salvos. Neste caso eu recomendaria a criar 3 tabelas, uma de "perfis", uma para as "contas" e outra para as "preferencias".

A tabela contas e perfis se relacionam `1:n` e a tabela preferencias se relaciona com a tabela perfis `1:1`. Não é necessário, a estrutura que descrevi funciona tanto "com" ou "sem" as chaves estrangeiras, mas como eu disse, a vantagem é amarrar os dados.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`contas` (
  `id_contas` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `senha` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_contas`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`perfis` (
  `id_perfis` INT NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `perfiscol` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `contas_id_contas` INT NOT NULL,
  `preferencias_id_preferencias` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_perfis`, `contas_id_contas`),
  INDEX `fk_perfis_contas_idx` (`contas_id_contas` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_perfis_preferencias1_idx` (`preferencias_id_preferencias` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_perfis_contas`
    FOREIGN KEY (`contas_id_contas`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`contas` (`id_contas`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_perfis_preferencias1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`preferencias_id_preferencias`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`preferencias` (`id_preferencias`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`preferencias` (
  `id_preferencias` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `preferencia1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `preferencia2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_preferencias`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

No entanto se for uma tabela sem chave estrangeira, ela terá que ter colunar para apontar as ids das outras tabelas, por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`contas` (
  `id_contas` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `login` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `senha` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_contas`))
ENGINE = myIsam;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`perfis` (
  `id_perfis` INT NOT NULL,
  `contas_id_contas` INT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_perfis`))
ENGINE = myIsam;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`preferencias` (
  `id_preferencias` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `perfis_id_perfis` INT NULL,
  `preferencia1` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `preferencia2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_preferencias`))
ENGINE = myIsam;
```

### Como usar as queries

Para logar será necessário apenas selecionar `contas`, e salvar o `id` na sessão.

```
SELECT id_contas, login, senha FROM contas WHERE login=? AND senha=?
```

Para exibir os perfis, você pode usar algo como

```
SELECT id_perfis, nome, perfiscol FROM perfis WHERE contas_id_contas=? #O ? deve ser o ID que foi salvo na sessão
```

Para exibir os perfis e configurações:

```
SELECT
    P1.id_perfis AS ID_PERFIL,
    P1.nome AS NOME,
    P1.perfiscol AS PERFIL_DATA,
    P2.id_preferencias AS ID_PREFERENCIA,
    P2.preferencia1 AS PREFERENCIA_1,
    P2.preferencia2 AS PREFERENCIA_2

FROM
    perfis P1, preferencias P2

where
    P1.id_perfis = P2.perfis_id_perfis
```

Comment: Estou tendo um pouco de dificuldades pra compreender, eu já estava tentando implementar o que o BlueX falou, mas sem chaves estrangeiras, apenas usando o `php` e `Join` pois já utilizei isso pra [algo parecido](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/17147) não sei se aquele exemplo poderia ser aplicado aqui, ou melhorado, por isso vou esperar mais um pouco antes de marcar alguma resposta.

Comment: @Florida editei a resposta, mas eu estou com uma duvida, você quer que o usuário filho acesse pela própria conta? Que tipo de dados você quer trazer? Talvez isto me ajude a formular as queries pra ti.

Comment: Não, o sistema de login fica apenas na conta principal,(conta pai), assim como o login, senha, e informações importantes relevantes a todos os usuários, nas contas filhos, ficam por exemplo o idioma, preferencias de abas, session particular do filho. Ou seja, a conta pai é como uma conta filho, mas é a principal e traz dados de login, senha, level e quantas contas filhos ele pode ter. Todos os filhos logam através da conta pai e dai fazem a escolha do perfil(filho) a qual querem usar. _Se não tiver entendio algo, pode perguntar._

Comment: @Florida, entendi, então soluções aqui parecem não ser uteis pra ti. Vou tentar reformular.

Comment: Assim deve funcionar, para evitar que fiquem _fragmentos_ quando alguma conta for deletada por exemplo, posso criar uma função no `php` e apagar os filhos dela. Os dois exemplos são bem úteis, quem preferir as chaves estrangeiras podem usa-las, gostei das duas alternativas.

Answer (score 2):

Quando desejamos desenvolver uma base de dados devemos estrutura-la afim de **criar relacionamentos entre as tabelas**, este relacionamento parte do *principio* de **haver algo em comum nas tabelas**, por exemplo:

**Tabela Pai:**

```
id | Username | Resto..-
 1 |   João   |  ...
 2 |   Maria  |  ...
```

**Tabela Filhos:**

```
id | pai_id | Username | Resto...
1  |   1    |  António |  ...
2  |   2    |  Pedro   |  ...
3  |   1    |  Miguel  |  ...
4  |   1    | Joaquim  |  ...
```

Repara que **existe um elemento em comum** em ambas as tabelas, neste caso o *field* `pai_id` refere-se ao id existente na tabela pai, obviamente cabe a ti escolher o nome dado ao respetivo *field*, mas por norma `pai_id` provem da seguinte *nomenclatura* `tabela_field`, desta forma as coisas tornam-se mais organizadas e fáceis de entender.

Lembro dizer que os *fields* `id` existentes nas tabelas pai e filho são `AUTO_INCREMENT`, enquanto que o *field* `pai_id` não, este é preenchido apenas quando o filho é criado.

**Estrutura de uma base de dados:**

[image: Estrutura de uma base de dados]

Esta imagem demonstra a *estrutura de uma base de dados* e podes ver que existem os tais **elementos em comum**.

**Na prática:**

Para obteres o respetivo filho, o query seria algo como isto:

```
SELECT * FROM `filhos` WHERE pai_id='valor';
```

Para excluir poderias utilizar o mesmo *field* como identificação:

```
DELETE FROM `filhos` WHERE pai_id='valor';
```

Isto tudo dito foi a base para o desenvolvimento da tua aplicação, cabe a ti estruturar à tua maneira.

---

Em relação ao sistema e seguindo um pouco a tua lógica (apesar de não saber ao certo como o sistema do netflix funciona) vou apresentar uma ideia de implementação deste sistema:

- A conta principal encontraria-se na tabela `pai` e esta seria responsável pelos pagamentos.
- As sub-contas estariam na tabela `filhos` e estas seriam responsáveis por filtrar conteúdos.

**Funcionamento:** O utilizador faria o login na conta principal e por sua vez apareceria uma lista com as sub-contas, o utilizador escolheria a sua sub-conta e faria o login nessa sub-conta.